# UIButtons don't align correctly upon first load of View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uistoryboard

I have a ViewController/View in a TabBar Controller that has 8 UIButtons in a 2x4 grid, sized 75x75, each with a 75x75 background image set on them. Currently, I've hard coded the XY positions in the Size Inspector in Interface Builder.

When I first load the View, by clicking on the tab bar icon, the bottom two buttons get squished against the row above them - as per this picture:

[image]

Each button triggers a segue that launches another ViewController with a WebView in it :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"playVimeo" sender:sender];
```

In that WebView, there is a back button that triggers another segue to return to the thumbnails page :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"returnToThumbnails" sender:sender];
```

When I press the back button and return to the thumbnail view for a second time, the buttons snap to the right place, unlike when they first load, as per this picture:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my Storyboard:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here ? I am lost...

Thanks in advance!

Jesse

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but your storyboard setup is wrong. You shouldn't "go back" to the thumbnail view with a segue (unless it's an unwind segue) because you're not really going back -- you're creating a new instance of the thumbnail view. Other than unwinds, segues ALWAYS instantiate new controllers.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I see what you're saying, but the fact is that the View only aligns properly when I use a segue, and not when it loads from the tab bar... ?!?

Comment: So, as an aside, how should I return to the ViewController ? I don't wan't to embed this is a navigation controller if I can help it...

Comment: Either use an unwind segue or, just use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] in the second controller.

Comment: I'm getting an Assertion Faiure when I try to put in my IBAction method...

Comment: When you put what in your action method?

Comment: Sorry, when I put the dismissViewControllerAnimated method...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36583/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jesses-co-tt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue went away when I unselected "Use Autolayout" in the file inspector of the UIViewControllers.

Though as rdelmar pointed out in the comments, it is funny that it was working at all, as I was actually creating a new ViewController with every segue from my back button, and not popping back to the previous existing ViewController. It should have been working the same in both ways, as the View was always loading 'for the first time' ...